# how can I have a countDown timer start form custom time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

with this count down timer I can count from current dateTime but how can I have a count down timer from the custom date time.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let userCalendar = Calendar.current
let requestedComponent: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(dddd), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire() }

func printTime()
{
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    let startTime = Date()
    let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017/10/18 14:02:00")
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime!)
    lableText.text = "\(timeDifference.month!):\(timeDifference.day!): \(timeDifference.hour!):\(timeDifference.minute!):\(timeDifference.second!)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this:

```
let startTime = Date()
```

to something like this:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let components = NSDateComponents.init();
components.year = year
components.month = month
components.day = day
let startTime = calendar.date(from: components)
```

I set example year, month and day you can set the complete date time with zone too.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make change as per below

```
    var startTime = Date()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
           dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
           dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
           dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
           startTime = Date()
            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                    timer.fire()
         }

  func printTime()  {
          let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017/10/18 14:02:00")
          let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime!)
          lableText.text = "\(timeDifference.month!):\(timeDifference.day!): \(timeDifference.hour!):\(timeDifference.minute!):\(timeDifference.second!)"
                    }
```